# Specifying a timeframe in a plot indicator

Tags: pine-script

I have this code that I use to draw the 5 minutes chart moving averages on the seconds based time frames but not on the higher time frames:

```
//@version=4
study("5min MAs", overlay=true)

plot(timeframe.isseconds ? security(syminfo.tickerid, '5', ema(close[1],9),  lookahead=barmerge.lookahead_on) : ema(close,9) , title="9EMA", color=#ff6d00, linewidth=1)
plot(timeframe.isseconds ? security(syminfo.tickerid, '5', ema(close[1],20),  lookahead=barmerge.lookahead_on) : ema(close,20) , title="20EMA", color=#ffeb3b, linewidth=1)
plot(timeframe.isseconds ? security(syminfo.tickerid, '5', sma(close[1],200),  lookahead=barmerge.lookahead_on) : sma(close,200) , title="200SMA", color=#ff2fbb, linewidth=1)
```

I'd like the code to also be able to draw the 5 min based MAs on the 1 and 2 minute charts along with the seconds time frames.
I tried using the `timeframe.isintraday` instead of `timeframe.isseconds` function but the 5 min based MAs are also drawn on the time frames above 5 minutes (eg. 30min, 60min etc.) which I don't want.

Is there a way to isolate only for the 1 and 2 minutes timeframes?
I think I need to declare a variable with `timeframe.period` but I am not sure how to integrate it.

Thanks,
Eric

Answer (score 0):

I managed to figure it out

```
//@version=4
study("5min MAs", overlay=true)


plot(timeframe.isseconds or (timeframe.isintraday and (timeframe.multiplier <= 2)) ? security(syminfo.tickerid, '5', ema(close[1],9),  lookahead=barmerge.lookahead_on) : ema(close,9) , title="9EMA", color=#ff6d00, linewidth=1)
plot(timeframe.isseconds or (timeframe.isintraday and (timeframe.multiplier <= 2)) ? security(syminfo.tickerid, '5', ema(close[1],20),  lookahead=barmerge.lookahead_on) : ema(close,20) , title="20EMA", color=#ffeb3b, linewidth=1)
plot(timeframe.isseconds or (timeframe.isintraday and (timeframe.multiplier <= 2)) ? security(syminfo.tickerid, '5', sma(close[1],200),  lookahead=barmerge.lookahead_on) : sma(close,200) , title="200SMA", color=#ff2fbb, linewidth=1)
```